# Is it possible to return (*ptr)[2] type?

Tags: c, matrix, malloc

If not, how can I represent that using a `*ptr`? this seems to evade me...

Basically I want to return `N by 2` matrix and I want it to be consistent in memory.

Comment: C or C?? Pick _one_...

Comment: type (*funcname(parameters))[2]{ ... }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`typedef`s are your friends:

```
typedef int A[2]; // typedef an array of 2 ints

A *foo(int n)
{
    A *a = malloc(n * sizeof(A));   // malloc N x 2 array

    // ... do stuff to initialise a ...

    return a;                       // return it
}
```

---

To see why `typedef`s are useful, consider the equivalent implementation without a `typedef` (thanks are due to @JohnBode for contributing the correct syntax for this example):

```
int (*foo(int n))[2]
{
    int (*a)[2] = malloc(n * sizeof *a);   // malloc N x 2 array

    // ... do stuff to initialise a ...

    return a;                              // return it
}
```

---

Note that [cdecl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cdecl) is a useful tool for encoding and decoding cryptic C declarations - there's even a handy online version at [cdecl.org](http://www.cdecl.org).

Comment: do I have to use typedef for this? why is that?

Comment: You don't *have* to, but in general it makes the code more readable and it's much easier to get the syntax right.

Comment: Can you update your answer for the way to avoid typedef?

Comment: No - you're free to ignore my advice if you wish, but I'm not going to give you a bad answer. See @BLUEPIXY's comment above if you want to do it the hard way.

Comment: I'm not ignoring your advice I'm using this as a learning tool.

Comment: OK - it would probably take me about 15 minutes to get the syntax right for a non-typedef'd answer anyway (especially the malloc part) - can you see now why the typedef method might be preferable ?

Comment: Obviously. Although IMHO the true test for knowing a language is how to read every expression - no matter how awkward it may seem. Shortcuts are for the ones who are confident enough, I'm not that kind of a C programmer - yet.

Comment: @MuliYulzary: without the typedef, it would be `int (*foo( int n ))[2] {...}`.  Yes, it looks weird.  The `malloc` call would look like `int (*a)[2] = malloc( n * sizeof *a);`

Comment: Thanks @JohnBode - I've folded the code from your comment into the answer now, for the sake of completeness - I hope that's OK with you.